# How long does metrics data in AWS cloudwatch maintained

Tags: amazon-web-services

Their API reference says the date start date should be less than 14 days from the current date. I would like to know whether the data older than this is deleted and not available

Comment: 2022: ['Metrics cannot be deleted, but they automatically expire after 15 months if no new data is published to them. Data points older than 15 months expire on a rolling basis; as new data points come in, data older than 15 months is dropped.'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Metric)

Answer (score 17):

Metrics used to be kept for 2 weeks, but as @sfgeorge points out, AWS has increased storage times.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html

> When you use the mon-put-data command,
>   you must use a date range within the
>   past two weeks. There is currently no
>   function to delete data points. Amazon
>   CloudWatch automatically deletes data
>   points with a timestamp more than two
>   weeks old.

Comment: It seems unclear now:  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_the_minimum_time_interval_granularity_for_the_data_that_Amazon_CloudWatch.  But this link does talk about using the API to store the data somewhere else.

Comment: This answer was edited to reflect the change in cloudwatch metrics retention, see @sfgeorge's answer

Comment: This link appears specific to EC2 (although I think the answer is the same for CloudWatch, generally).

Answer (score 15):

As of November 1st, 2016, [the retention window for AWS metrics in CloudWatch has expanded from 14 days to 15 months](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-update-extended-metrics-retention-user-interface-update/).

Note that the data granularity will be reduced when you widen your range beyond the past 15 days:

> - One minute data points are available for 15 days.
> - Five minute data points are available for 63 days.
> - One hour data points are available for 455 days (15 months).

Comment: You can find this documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

As found in https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/ :

Q: Will I lose the metrics data if I disable monitoring for an Amazon EC2 instance?

You can retrieve metrics data for any Amazon EC2 instance up to 2 weeks from the time you started to monitor it. After 2 weeks, metrics data for an Amazon EC2 instance will not be available if monitoring was disabled for that Amazon EC2 instance. If you want to archive metrics beyond 2 weeks you can do so by calling mon-get-stats command from the command line and storing the results in Amazon S3 or Amazon SimpleDB

Comment: this is no longer true, see @sfgeorge's answer